# Docker: How to create an environment variable in the host machine that points to a directory in a docker container?

Tags: docker, environment-variables, buildout

I am using Docker to run four containers to run a backend web application. The backend web application uses `buildout` to assemble the software.

However, the frontend, which is installed and runs on the host machine (that is, not using Docker), needs to access the `buildout` directory inside one of the four docker containers.

Moreover, the frontend uses an environment variable called `NTI_BUILDOUT_PATH` that is defined on the host machine. `NTI_BUILDOUT_PATH` must point to the `buildout` directory, which is inside the aforementioned container.

My problem is that I do not know how to define `NTI_BUILDOUT_PATH` such that it contains a directory that points towards the `buildout` directory that is needed by the front end for SSL certificates and other purposes.

I have researched around the web and read about `volumes` and `bind mounts` but I do not think they can help me in my case.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] demonstrating this?  In general host processes can't directly access the container filesystems (and _vice versa_) so you probably need to rearrange this to run more of your build process outside of Docker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you can do that is by copying your `buildout` folder into the host machine using `docker cp`

```sh
docker cp <backend-container-id>:<path-to-buildout> <path-to-host-folder>
```

For Example if your backend's container_id is d1b5365c5bca and your `buildout` folder is in `/app/buildout` inside the container. You can use the following command to copy it to the host.

```
docker cp d1b5365c5bca:/app/buildout /home/mahmoud/app/buildout
```

After that you `docker rm` all your containers and recreate new ones with a `bind mount` to the buildout folder in the host. So following the previous example we'll have

```
docker run -v /home/mahmoud/app/buildout:/app/buildout your-backend-image
docker run -v /home/mahmoud/app/buildout:/app/buildout -e NTI_BUILDOUT_PATH=/app/buildout your-frontend-image
```